# Entering a pattern using the keyboard

Tags: external-keyboard, pattern-lock, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using a keyboard with my android phone (connected via a usb otg cable)

I have noted that hitting SPC or RET when the phone is locked takes me to the unlock screen where i have to enter a pattern.

Is there a keyboard shortcut means for entering a pattern?

If not plan B is to switch to a PIN - but I quite like the pattern, hence the question..

Comment: Can you not use a mouse?

Comment: yes you could do that - but in this *particular* scenario, i.e. a wired usb keyboard using up the only usb otg connection, I can't do that. I am also interested to know if it is possible. I do have a wireless keyboard/mouse combo and that does work with the dongle plugged into the otg cable, however on that keyboard all the keycaps are moved around as I am a colemak fiend. a little complicated i know..